# convert vertical text to horizontal text in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I want to convert the vertical text in my file to horizontal. like

```
1  
2  
3
```

to

```
1 2 3
```

I can do this using the tr command `tr '\n' ' ' <file`

but I want to do this using  vim

Answer (score 3):

Select the lines and join them  with `J`.

From `:h J` :

```
                            *J*
J           Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
            Remove the indent and insert up to two spaces (see
            below).

                            *v_J*
{Visual}J       Join the highlighted lines, with a minimum of two
            lines.  Remove the indent and insert up to two spaces
            (see below).  {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy one. Use a range from first line until last one and join them with an space between them:

```
:0,$join
```

Comment: Or even shorter `:%j`

Answer (score 2):

And, just for the fun of it:

```
:{fromLine},{toLine}!tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
By replacing `\n` with

```
:{fromLine},{toLine}s/\n/ /g
```